# Posts from wordpress to facebook page

Tags: facebook

I think I might be doing something wrong. But, first, I was posting from my WordPress to my Facebook page with the new Facebook plugin.  Things didn’t go very well though: no text excerpt sometimes didn't show featured image. So I disabled it from plugin, and used the API.  It is posting, but now the excerpt comes with html tags, e.g.:

```
<p> this is a blog post</p>
<p> <em> this is the post content</em> </p>
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that so?

Because *you* are sending HTML code to Facebook …?

Strip the HTML code out, and just send the raw text. You can try and use `strip_tags` for that – if your HTML code is well-formed, then it should work fine. (If it’s not, though, it might strip to much.)